# Hide top admin panel for non admin and non editors

Tags: admin, users, user-roles, content-restriction, privileges

So i came to three posible solutions to this question and can't decide which is better. What is your opinion?

First solution:

```
if ( ( in_array('administrator', userdata('role')) || in_array('editor', 
userdata('role')) ) == false)
{   
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

Second one:

```
if( ( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) == false )
{
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

Third one:

```
$allowed_roles = array('editor', 'administrator');
if( array_intersect($allowed_roles, userdata('role') ) == false ) {
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

User data function:

```
function userdata($userdata){
$userinfo = wp_get_current_user();
if ($userdata == 'nick')
return $userinfo ->user_login;
if ($userdata == 'mail')
return $userinfo ->user_email;
if ($userdata == 'id')
return $userinfo ->ID;
if ($userdata == 'role')
return $userinfo ->roles;
else
return 'Eror';
}
```

I am voting for the third solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i am using;

```
add_action('init', 'blockusers_init');

function blockusers_init() {
    if (is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator') &&
        !(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)) {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }
}
```

It's possible the best one.

EDIT : You need a custom login page for reach `wp-admin`. This code redirect to homepage if you enter directly to `wp-admin`.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is inefficient as it runs the `userdata` function twice, but that is easily fixed:

```
$roles = userdata('role');
if ( ( in_array('administrator', $roles) || in_array('editor', $roles) ) == false )
{   
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

However the third method does essentially the same thing in a better way.

The second method uses `current_user_can`, which is unreliable when used to check roles, as per the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can).

However, if you are certain of the capabilities different roles will have now or in future, you could do something like this:

```
if( !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') )
{
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

By default only admins and editors have this capability, so checking for this tells you what you need to know, if the default is certain to be used.

Comment: Excelent answer and well explainded. Thanks for your feedback.